# Carriage return character not being matched in Swift

Tags: swift, character-encoding

I'm trying to parse a file that (apparently) ends its lines with carriage returns, but they aren't being matched as such in Swift, despite having the same UTF8 value. I can see possible fixes for the problem, but I'm curious as to what these characters actually are.

Here's some sample code, with the output below. (CR is set using Character("\r"), although I've tried it using "\r" as well.

```
try f.forEach() { c in
            print(c, terminator:" ") // DBG
            if (c == "\r") {
                print("Carriage return found!")
            }
            print(String(c).utf8.first!, terminator:" ")//DBG
            print(String(describing:pstate)) // DBG
            ...
            case .field:
                switch c {
                case CR,LF :
                    self.endline()
                    pstate = .eol
```

When it reaches the end of  line (which shows up as such in my text editors), I get this:

```
. 46 field
0 48 field

 13 field
I 73 field
```

It doesn't seem to be matching using == or in the switch statement. Is there another approach I should be using for this character?

(I'll note that the parsing works fine with files that terminate in newlines.)

Comment: You can simply check if your character `isNewline` if you are coding in Swift 5 or later. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127014-isnewline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I determined what the problem was. By looking at `c.unicodeScalars` I discovered that the end of line character was in fact "\r\n", not just "\r". As seen in my code I was only taking the first when printing it out as UTF-8. I don't know if that's something from String.forEach or in the file itself.

I know that there are tests to determine if something is a newline. Swift 5 has them directly (`c.isNewline`), and there is also the CharacterSet approach as noted by Bill Nattaner.

I'm happier with something that will work in my switch statement (and thus I'll define each one explicitly), but that might change if I expect to deal with a wider variety of files.

Comment: In Java `"\n" == "\r\n"`. I was wondering why same logic gives invalid results if in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little hazy as to what the `f.forEach` represents, but if your variable `c` is of type Character then you could replace your `if` statement with:

```
if "\(c)".rangeOfCharacter( from: CharacterSet.newlines ) != nil
{
    print("Carriage return found!")
}
```

That way you won't have to invent a list of all-possible new line characters.

Comment: f is a String, normally read in from a file. I think the forEach is what's confusing me here, as I don't know what it's grabbing.